# "emacs" key bindings for Firefox 46

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been happily using Firefox in Kubuntu 14.04, with "emacs" key bindings, by adding tho the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file:

```
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
```

However, now Firefox has been updated to 46, apparently with GTK3 (and, as with every second update, some other settings/extensions are screwed up), and that solution doesn't work. How can I easily get my Ctrl+U = "clear line" shortcut?

Comment: Now its firefox 47 and the proposed solution does not seem to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/gtk3-emacs-key-theme.html

Edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and add, inside the `[Settings]` section, this line:

```
gtk-key-theme-name = Emacs
```